# best way to make a page available in multiple languages in django cms

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, django-cms

What is the best way to make a page available in multiple languages in Django? I have followed the documentation and used `LANGUAGES` but I can't see the translated page.

I am stuck. Should I manage the `/en`, `/de`, etc urls by myself?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Django Internationalization , It is there in django
first create a "locale" folder in your django project,after that in settings.py include folder path .
eg-LOCALE_PATHS="projectpath/locale"

Add this to your middleware - 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware', in settings.py
and set USE_I18N = True in settings.py

After that in settings.py include this "django.core.context_processors.i18n", in template context processor

For html file -:
First you have to include template tag of Internationalization and then you can use template tags in all the static elements of html file
Eg-
{% load i18n %} put this on top of your html file 
and try this

*{% trans "put your static text here" %}* wherever static text is there in that page

In case of template variable in Django you can use this - 
{% blocktrans %}this is your translated {{ object }}{% endblocktrans %}

Now for django views you have to follow this-:

from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

> def view(request):
>      output = _("this is translated text")
>      return HttpResponse(output)

Comment: I have seen an application having internationalization done in Django. Developer of the site has just made different templates for different languages and manage them from views. i.e /en rendered the template content_en.html and /ru rendered the template content_ru.html. Which is confusing for me. is this called internationalization? I Appreciates you answer, will move toward your answer after getting clear from this confusion.